# Singleton for retaining state of UI across tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton, uitabbar

My app uses a tab bar to display 5 diff views. Each of these views has a narrow strip at the top which displays a twitter feed.. The twitter feed should maintain it's appearance across all tabs.

```
-----------------------------------------
| twitter feed scrolling to the left    | < this block stays here, text scrolls
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|           main bit of the view        |
|          changes according to tab     |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
|       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       | < tab bar
|       |       |       |       |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

I can't work out what would be the best pattern here for the code. Should I retain the twitter feed details (including UI?) in a Singleton and stick them into view with viewDidAppear? Or is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `UITabBarController` or a `UITabBar` by itself?  If it's a `UITabBar` by itself, you could simply put the twitter bar across the top and don't swap it out with the main content view.

If you're using a tab bar controller, this might work: set your app delegate (or some other singleton) as the delegate, and do:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Have an ivar called twitterBar.
    [viewController.view addSubview:twitterBar];
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I don't see a way to add a ViewController (twitterBar) to a view.

Comment: `[viewController.view addSubview:twitterBar.view]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume your current view controller tree looks like this:

```
UITabBarController
    ViewOneController
    ViewTwoController
    etc.
```

You could nest this one deeper:

```
UINavigationController
    UITabBarController
        ViewOneController
        ViewTwoController
        etc.
```

Then put the display at the top of the screen into the root `UIViewController`'s navigation bar. Or change it for your own subclass completely.